# Split class function into two separate header files

Tags: c++

I'm am trying to split the function definition into a different file separate from the declaration. I have no idea what is wrong. The errors received are as follows

[Errors Received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnQXg.png)

The code works when I have the definition in one header file the problem arises when I try to split the definition onto a different .cpp file.

I've tries changing Shapeclassdefinition.cpp to a .h file and use #include "Shapesclass.h". Still doesn't work

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Shapeclass.h"


int main() {

    int shapecount, shapetype[200],i,height[200], width[200];
    string name;

    Shape* p1[200];

    cout << "\t\tAREA CALULATOR\n\n";
    
    cout << "Enter Your Name ";
    cin >> name;
    
    
    
        cout << "Enter the amount of Shapes you want to calculate Area of:  ";
    cin >> shapecount;

    

    

    

    cout << "Enter '1' for Circle Enter '2' for Rectangle and '3' for Triangle: ";

    for ( i = 0; i < shapecount; i++)
    {
        cin >> shapetype[i];

    }
    
    for ( i = 0; i < shapecount; i++)
    {
        if (shapetype[i]==1)
        {
            cout << "Enter Radius of circle: ";
            cin >> width[i];
            p1[i] = new sphere(width[i],name);
            

        }

        else if (shapetype[i] == 2) {
            cout << "Enter width of rectangle: ";
            cin >> width[i];
            cout << "Enter height of rectangle: ";
            cin >> height[i];
            p1[i] = new rectangle(width[i],height[i],name);
        }

        else if (shapetype[i] == 3) {
            cout << "Enter base of triangle: ";
            cin >> width[i];
            cout << "Enter height of triangle: ";
            cin >> height[i];
            p1[i] = new triangle(width[i], height[i],name);


        }



    }


    cout << "Display Areas For Shapes\n";

    for ( i = 0; i < shapecount; i++)
    {
        p1[i]->display();
    }



}
```

**Shapesclass.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#ifndef SHAPE_DEF
#define SHAPE_DEF
// some declarations in
// the header file.


using namespace std;


class Shape
{

private:
    
protected:

    double area ;
    int height,width;
    string nama;

    void virtual calculate() = 0;

public:
    
    
    void display();

private:

};





class rectangle :public Shape {

public:
    rectangle(int width1, int height1, string name);
    void calculate();
};



class triangle :public Shape {

public:
    triangle(int width1, int height1, string name);
    
    void calculate();


};

class sphere :public Shape {

public:
    sphere(int width1, string name);

    void calculate();

};


#endif
```

**Shapeclassdefinition.cpp**

```
#include "Shapeclass.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

rectangle::rectangle(int width1, int height1, string name) {
    width = width1;
        height = height1;
        nama = name;
}

void rectangle::calculate() {

    area = height * width;
        cout << "Shape: Rectangle \n";
}





triangle::triangle (int width1, int height1, string name) {
    width = width1;
    height = height1;
    nama = name;

}

void triangle::calculate() {
    
    area = height * width * 0.5;
    cout << "Shape: Triangle \n";
}

sphere::sphere(int width1, string name) {
    width = width1;
    nama = name;
}

void sphere::calculate() {

    area = width * width * 3.14;
    cout << "Shape: Circle \n";
}


void Shape::display() {
    cout << "Name " << nama << endl;
    calculate();


    cout << "Width: " << width << endl;

    if (height <= 0)
        cout << "Height: " << height << endl;
    else
        cout << "N/A\n";


    cout << "Area: " << area << endl;
}
```

Comment: It is sadly. Shapeclassdefinition.cpp holds the definitions of the class functions for both class Shape triangle, rectangle and sphere. If you dont mind me asking. Why would you think that? It would help me tremendously

Comment: The previous response was in response to someone asking if `Shapeclassdefinition.cpp` was a part of the project

Comment: I removed that comment because the top errors suggested that it was part of the project even though the linker errors suggested it was not being compiled.

Comment: Sorry to bother you. Any particular reason why `Shapeclassdefinition.cpp` is not being compiled?

Comment: I can't see the problem.

Comment: @SlickMik Shapesclass.h and the source run fine for me. I'm assuming visual studio is not correctly linking the files. Can you check which source files are being linked? Is visual studio somehow ignoring your file?

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question but what do you mean by "Check which source files are linked"? The files are present in the solution explorer

Comment: I just added the files to a new project and it works now. I guess it just wasn't compiling for some odd reason. I hope this helps someone!